# Correct way to standardize interaction term with one binary and one continuous variable?

Tags: regression, interaction, regression-coefficients, stata

Say that I want to run a regression of Y on 1) a binary main effect (B); 2) a continuous main effect (C); and 3) an interaction of 1 and 2 (BC): `gen BC=B*C`.

0. If I do not standardize them, there is no problem: `reg Y B C BC`.

However, I think that the interpretation of variable C is a lot harder than if I were to standardize this variable (mean 0 and standard deviation 1). So standardize C to create C_S (`egen C_S=std(C)`). I do not think that it makes sense to standardize the discrete variable B.

The tricky thing is what to do with BC given that C is now standardized to be C_S. There seem to be three possibilities (all of which include the standardized C_S):

1. Do not standardize the interaction: `reg Y B C_S BC`
2. Re-create the interaction using the discrete B and the continuous C_S: `gen BC_2=B*C_S`
   Then re-run the regression using this new variable: `reg Y B C_S BC_2`
3. Instead, standardize the interaction term (that was created using B and C): `egen BC_3=std(BC)`.

Intuitively, option 2 seems to be the correct thing to do. However, I get weird results when I put it in a regression. This will use Stata. If necessary, I might do an R version too.

```
sysuse auto2, clear

*create outcome variable 
gen Y=price

*create dummy variable
gen B=foreign==1

gen C=weight

*create interaction term
gen BC = B*C

*create standardized weight
egen C_S = std(C)

*create standardized interaction 2 (use C_S)
gen BC_2 = B*C_S

*create standardized interaction 3 (standardize after)
egen BC_3 = std(BC)

*0. Baseline (nothing standardized)
reg Y B C BC

*1. interaction not standardized
reg Y B C_S BC

*2. using BC_2
reg Y B C_S BC_2

*3. using BC_3
reg Y B C_S BC_3
```

Here is the regression output:

Model 0 (baseline):

```
. reg Y B C BC

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           B |  -2171.597   2829.409    -0.77   0.445    -7814.676    3471.482
           C |   2.994814   .4163132     7.19   0.000     2.164503    3.825124
          BC |   2.367227   1.121973     2.11   0.038      .129522    4.604931
       _cons |  -3861.719   1410.404    -2.74   0.008    -6674.681   -1048.757
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Model 1 (do not standardize interaction):

```
reg Y B C_S BC

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           B |  -2171.597   2829.409    -0.77   0.445    -7814.676    3471.483
         C_S |    2327.55   323.5559     7.19   0.000     1682.238    2972.862
          BC |   2.367227   1.121973     2.11   0.038     .1295219    4.604931
       _cons |   5180.999   312.3268    16.59   0.000     4558.083    5803.915
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Note that the coefficients on B and BC are the same as in the baseline model.

Model 2 (use BC_2, the one that multiples B with C_S):

```
. reg Y B C_S BC_2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           B |   4976.148   910.5648     5.46   0.000     3160.084    6792.212
         C_S |    2327.55   323.5559     7.19   0.000     1682.238    2972.862
        BC_2 |   1839.793   871.9902     2.11   0.038     100.6635    3578.923
       _cons |   5180.999   312.3268    16.59   0.000     4558.083    5803.915
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*In this model, which is the one I think makes most sense, we have very different numbers for B and the interaction, but the same for C_S. B completely flipped signs, which is confusing.

*Model 3 (where we standardize BC):

```
reg Y B C_S BC_3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           B |  -2171.597   2829.409    -0.77   0.445    -7814.676    3471.482
         C_S |    2327.55   323.5559     7.19   0.000     1682.238    2972.862
        BC_3 |   2582.089   1223.809     2.11   0.038      141.278    5022.899
       _cons |   6810.867   874.8334     7.79   0.000     5066.066    8555.667
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*B is the same as in models 0 and 1. C_S is the same as in models 1, 2, and 3. The interaction term is different than all other models.

Again, Model 2 seems ex ante most correct, but the flipped sign on B is unintuitive to me and I would have expected B to be the same as in the baseline model 0. My goal is to find a model that uses a standardized C. I thought the interpretation of BC_2 is: for people for whom B==1, then a one standard deviation increase in C is associated with an increase of Y of ... - Is this correct?

What is going on? Which model is correct?

Note that my question is related to [Standardize binary variable to create interaction term in regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180655/standardize-binary-variable-to-create-interaction-term-in-regression), but I didn't feel like this really answered my questions.

Correlations (where B2 and C2 are squared):

```
             |        Y        B        C      C_S       BC       B2       C2
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
           Y |   1.0000
           B |   0.0487   1.0000
           C |   0.5386  -0.5928   1.0000
         C_S |   0.5386  -0.5928   1.0000   1.0000
          BC |   0.1375   0.9771  -0.5156  -0.5156   1.0000
          B2 |   0.0487   1.0000  -0.5928  -0.5928   0.9771   1.0000
          C2 |   0.5760  -0.5663   0.9915   0.9915  -0.5012  -0.5663   1.0000
```

Comment: In model 2, have you tried to standardize B? The flip of sign and the new significance is intriguing.

Comment: If I re-run model 2 but with a standardized B, all coefficients are positive (note that I am keeping BC_2 as defined above). If I define, say, BC_4 to be B_S*C_S (which makes more sense), all coefficients are also positive.

Comment: I'm not familair with STata, but does the fact that BC_2 used « gen » instead of « egen » changes something.

Comment: No, that difference is just an unintuitive way in which you make variables in different ways in Stata. It is correct.

Comment: Then, the only explanation i see is that model 2 alters high-order correlations. Can you check the correlation matrices between model 0 and model 2 for Y, B, C, BC, B^2, C^2.

Comment: I just added this to the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that your `Model 2` makes the most sense if you wish to standardize your continuous predictor `C`. The confusion comes from what the intercept and the coefficient for the binary predictor `B` mean in `Model 0` versus `Model 2`.

I assume that Stata is using treatment coding of the predictors, and that by standardizing `C` you mean subtracting its mean and dividing by its standard deviation.

Then in `Model 0` the intercept (`_cons`) is the estimated outcome  when `C = 0` and `B = 0`. The coefficient for `B` in `Model 0` is the *difference* from that outcome when `B = 1` and `C` is still at 0.

In `Model 2`, the intercept is the estimated outcome when `B = 0` and `C_S = 0`; equivalently, when `C` is at its original mean value. If `C` is associated with outcome and didn't have an original mean value of 0, that should be a good deal different from the intercept in `Model 0` even if there is no interaction with `B`, representing the outcome difference between `C` at 0 and `C` at its mean. So the change in intercept between models is expected.

Furthermore in `Model 2`, the coefficient for `B` represents the difference from the `Model 2` intercept outcome value when `B = 1` and `C_S` is still at 0 (or `C` is at its original mean value). If there is an interaction between `B` and `C`, then the magnitude of the association of B with outcome would differ depending on whether `C` is at 0 as in `Model 0` or at its mean value as in `Model 2`.  That's exactly what you're finding, and expected if there is an interaction.

You can find equations illustrating how simply centering a continuous predictor affects the intercept and the coefficients of other predictors interacting with it in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/417159/28500). If *all you did was center* the continuous predictor, those equations show that the associated interaction coefficients don't change. For example, the interaction coefficient in `Model 0` between the continuous predictor `C` and the binary predictor `B` is the outcome difference following a *unit change* in `C`, between `B = 0`  and `B = 1`. In a linear model, the effect of a unit change in `C` is the same regardless of whether you are starting from `C = 0` or from `C` at its mean value.

But in forming the `C_S` predictor for `Model 2` you didn't just center; you also scaled by the original standard deviation of `C`. So the coefficients for `C_S`  and for the `C_S:B` interaction represent the effects of unit changes *in the* `C_S` *scale*, not in the original `C` scale. The coefficients associated with `C` in `Model 0` thus differ from those associated with `C_S` in `Model 2`, in a ratio determined by the standard deviation of `C` used in scaling to get `C_S`.

Comment: This helps a ton. Thanks!

Comment: Would you also mind including the interpretations of the interaction terms for `Model 0` vs. `Model 2`? This will help me determine which of the two models makes most sense in my application. No worries if not as you have already answered the original question.

Comment: @bill999 added a bit to the end to address that. Remember that in forming `C_S` you didn't just center `C` but you also scaled by the standard deviation. So the coefficients associated with `C` (both on its own and in the interaction) differ from those associated with `C_S`, just like coefficients for a distance measured in miles would differ from those for the same distance measured in millimeters.

Comment: I appreciate it.